# Accessing @IBAction's property of ViewController and pass it to SecondViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, properties, swift4, ios11

How to access **`points`** property from IBAction method of **`ViewController`** and pass it to **`scoreLabel`** of **`SecondViewController`**?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var points: Int = 0

    @IBAction func action(sender: UIButton) {
        points += 1
    }
}



class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Maybe I put it in wrong place?

Comment: Where did you put my method?

Comment: Are you segueing to `SecondViewController` with an identifier?

Comment: Yes. It's here: performSegueWithIdentifier("showScore", sender: self)

Comment: There's an error: secondViewController.scoreLabel.text = String(points)

Comment: Just checking: You put the method in `ViewController`, correct?

Comment: Correct. Error is "Thread 1 Exc Bad Instruction"

Comment: Hmm. Try this instead: `secondViewController.scoreLabel.text = "\(points)"`

Comment: Sorry about that. Check my updated answer. It should work...

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Cool. It works. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162459/discussion-between-xcoder-and-andy).

Comment: @Xcoder, could you help me with a macOS question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478503/segue-doesnt-work-in-macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is assuming that you are segueing to `SecondViewController` from `ViewController`.

In `SecondViewController`, declare a variable called `score` or something like that:

```
var score: Int = 0
```

In `ViewController`, implement the `prepareForSegue` method like so:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifierForSecondViewController" {
        if let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController.score = points
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `SecondViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, you can set score to your label:

```
scoreLabel.text = String(score)
```