# Segue doesn't work in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, segue, swift4, viewcontroller

I have `NSSlider` in `ViewController` that must pass integer value to `SecondViewController` via segue of type `Show` and update a View every time I move it. So, moving slider I interactively shuffle images in `SecondViewController`'s window.

I spent a week trying to implement such a behaviour of `NSSlider` but I failed. Maybe I made wrong connections in Interface Builder. I don't know. If you know any other method to make `NSSlider` work for shuffling images, tell me, please.

See updated answer for detailed information.

Really appreciate any help!!!

**ViewController**

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: NSSlider!

    @IBAction func passData(_ sender: NSSlider) {        
        func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: NSSlider?) {
            if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "SegueIdentifierForSecondVC" {
                if let secondViewController = segue.destinationController as? SecondViewController {
                    secondViewController.imagesQuantity = slider.intValue 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
import Cocoa

class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

    var imagesQuantity: Int = 1

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()

        print(imagesQuantity)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong in my code?

Any help appreciated.

> **UPDATED ANSWER**

**VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
import Cocoa

extension NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier {
    static let secondVC = NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier("SegueIdentifierForSecondVC")
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: NSSlider!

    @IBAction func segueData(_ sender: NSSlider) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: .secondVC, sender: slider)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier! == .secondVC {
            if let secondViewController =
                segue.destinationController as? SecondViewController {
                secondViewController?.imagesQty = slider.integerValue 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
import Cocoa

class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

    var imagesQty = 30  

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        //let arrayOfViews: [NSImageView] = [view01...view12]

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Desktop/ArrayOfElements")

        do {
            let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]).reversed()
            let photos = fileURLs.filter { $0.pathExtension == "jpg" }

            for view in arrayOfViews {
                //"imagesQty" is here
                let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imagesQty-1)))
                let image = NSImage(data: try Data(contentsOf: photos[i]))
                view.image = image
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: NSSlider?)` inside the `IBAction` method? Put it outside, and instead in it write `self.perform(segue: SegueIdentifierForSecondVC sender:slider)`

Comment: You seem to have some knowledge in coding. Don't you see that you have a method inside another? `@IBAction func passData(_ sender: NSSlider){}` and `func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: NSSlider?) {}` being `@IBAction func passData(_ sender: NSSlider){unc prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: NSSlider?) {}}` instead of being one after the other? So in `passData()` call `performSegue()` and it should trigger `prepareForSegue()` (if it has the correct declaration according to the one in the doc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is not in the code.

You have to connect the segue to the **`ViewController`**, not to the `WindowController`.

Connect the slider action to the `IBAction` (not to the segue) and the segue from `ViewController` to `SecondViewController` (not from the slider).

And if the class of the second view controller is `SecondViewController` it should be indicated in the window controller. Where does `SecondVC` come from?

[image]

And once again the suggestion to create an extension of `NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier`

```
extension NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier {
    static let secondVC = NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier("SegueIdentifierForSecondVC")
}
```

and to use it in these two methods. And force cast the `segue.destinationController`. It must not crash if everything is hooked up properly.

```
@IBAction func segueData(_ sender: NSSlider) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: .secondVC, sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier, identifier == .secondVC {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationController as! SecondViewController
        secondViewController.imagesQty = slider.integerValue
    }
}
```

Finally `NSImage` got its own initializer taking an URL

```
let image = NSImage(contentsOf: photos[i])
```

Comment: But photos update only after closing/opening a Second Window. How to update photos without closing a window?

Comment: Also there's yellow triangle: file:///Users/me/Desktop/Pixie/Pixie/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: “Aux Window Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access via -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:]

Comment: Basically you can delete the second window controller. To show the second view controller in the same window please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139294/how-does-one-display-a-new-view-controller-in-the-same-mac-window or http://theiconmaster.com/2015/03/transitioning-between-view-controllers-in-the-same-window-with-swift-mac/

Comment: I deleted second window controller. But how to update views moving the slider in real-time?

Comment: That's a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524384/how-to-update-nsimageview-using-nsslider

Comment: I can award a bounty to you in 12 hours))

Comment: App works fine. Thank you one more time for your help! I have just one question: If I move a slider to the highest value (in my case 200) it shuffles my photos. But if I move it to 1 it fills all the views with photo number 256. I understand that it's `Int8` type. How can I get rid of it? I need a range much more than 256? I tried to assign type `Int16` but I couldn't.

Comment: Where does this `Int8` come from?

Comment: I suppose from slider.

Comment: I printed `photos[i]` in the loop and got this: file:///Users/me/Desktop/ArrayOfElements/0256.jpg

Comment: No, `intValue` is `Int32` and `integerValue` is `Int64`. You need to set the `maxValue` property of the slider (which is a `Double`) to the number of photos - 1.

Comment: Can a number of photos be more than slider's range? I use `.reversed` method to show just 1 last photo on all 12 views. (for instance my photo library contains 1000 photos, but slider's range is 200). So I can show only 200 out of 1000 photos in views.

Comment: It can be more but it shouldn't be less (to avoid an out-of-range exception)

Comment: Ok, I understand it. So, at the moment I have 205 photos in macOS folder and their names are `0201.jpg` to `0405.jpg` (I used frame-padding `%04d`). As I said I'm using `.reversed` method. In this case app shows me photo `0256.jpg` when I move a slider to `1` (instead of `0405.jpg`). This is quite strange!

Comment: I forgot to say: I'm making this app for my own work. I'm compositing artist working in Nuke, Fusion and Shake. So I need this app to watch compositing sequences of files.)) Maybe you think: this guy is strange, he needs strange app)))

Comment: Well, you can see a lot of real strange stuff here on SO 

Comment: The issue on `0256.jpg` is not correct. Or it's an Xcode's cache. Or it is side-effect of `arc4random_uniform` method. I tried to work with images `0001.jpg`...`0200.jpg`. For slider `value = 1` application chose `0090.jpg` (not `0200.jpg`)

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func passData(_ sender: NSSlider) {        
    func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: NSSlider?) {
        if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "SegueIdentifierForSecondVC" {
            if let secondViewController = segue.destinationController as? SecondViewController {
                secondViewController.imagesQuantity = slider.intValue 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should be

```
@IBAction func passData(_ sender: NSSlider) {        

}

func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: NSSlider?) {
    if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "SegueIdentifierForSecondVC" {
        if let secondViewController = segue.destinationController as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController.imagesQuantity = slider.intValue 
        }
    }
}
```

Because you have a method inside another while they should be one after the other.

Now, you need to modify `passData(_sender:)`. You need to call inside `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender)` inside it.
If will trigger at some point `prepare(for:sender:)`. I'm saying at "some point" because there is at least a `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` call before the `prepare(for:sender:)` is called.

So now do:

```
@IBAction func passData(_ sender: NSSlider) {        
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifierForSecondVC"  sender:nil)
}
```

Comment: Is `prepare(for segue:sender:)` called? For the identifier, it seems correct, it's just that I'm more used to iOS than macOS. What window does it open? secondVC? New one? Is secondVC alreay on screen when you want to update the value?

Comment: Slider opens the window of SecondVC and doesn't update the value(((

Comment: Again: Is `prepare(for segue:sender:)` called? Could you add a `print()` inside it? Also, if it's called, is it printed before or after `print(imagesQuantity)`?

Comment: I'm wondering if `func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: NSSlider?) {` maybe changed with the correct one from the doc.