# How to update NSImageView using NSSlider?

Tags: macos, swift4, nsview, nsslider

I have an `NSSlider` in `FirstViewController`. I have 12 `NSImageViews` in `SecondViewController`. I'd like to move a slider in first window and shuffle images in these 12 views in second window.

How to update these `NSImageViews` every time when moving the slider?

**SecondViewController**

```
var imagesQty = 100  

override func viewWillAppear() {

    super.viewWillAppear()

    //let arrayOfViews: [NSImageView] = [view01,...view12]

    for view in arrayOfViews {
        let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imagesQty-1)))
        let image = NSImage(data: try Data(contentsOf: photos[i]))
        view.image = image
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: NSSlider!

@IBAction func segueData(_ sender: NSSlider) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: .secondVC, sender: slider)
}
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier! == .secondVC {
        if let secondViewController =
            segue.destinationController as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController?.imagesQty = slider.integerValue 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all be aware that any move of the slider performs a new segue. To avoid that declare a boolean property which is set when the segue is performed the first time and could be reset after the second view controller has been dismissed.

To update the value in the second view controller keep the reference and call a method

Actually with this code you don't need the slider `IBOutlet`

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {


    var secondControllerIsPresented = false
    var secondController : SecondViewController?

...


    @IBAction func segueData(_ sender: NSSlider) {

        if !secondControllerIsPresented {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: .secondVC, sender: sender)
            secondControllerIsPresented = true
        } else {
            secondController?.updateArray(value: sender.integerValue)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier, identifier == .secondVC {
            let secondViewController = segue.destinationController as! SecondViewController
            secondController = secondViewController
            let slider = sender as! NSSlider
            secondViewController.imagesQty = slider.integerValue
        }
    }

...
```

---

```
class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

...


   func updateArray(value : Int) {
       print(value)
   }
```

Honestly I would use a button to perform the segue and move the slider into the second view controller. To shuffle the array use an `Array` extension and as view an `NSCollectionView` rather than a bunch of image views

Comment: Could you tell me how many years you spent to gain such a level in programming?

Comment: About half a year to understand the basics of object oriented programming. I read a book and the Objective-C language guide. I never wanted to copy and paste code together without knowing what's going on. It's like a real language: You have more fun if you speak the language fluently. Then about a year to understand the most frequently used frameworks (`Foundation`, `AppKit`, later `UIKit`). Then the switch to Swift was a quote small step. But again I **read** the entire language guide.